# Firebase Messaging Web getToken returns an expired token after 1-2 days of working correctly (that cannot be deleted)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have a firebase messaging service worker setup to custom handle push notifications (data messaging) in my web app that uses messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler to handle background messages. The app works perfectly in localhost, but only for a few hours or 1-2 days on my dev server, after which it stops receiving any notifications.

The problem is that when I load the page and I call firebase messaging.getToken(...) to register it to my server, when a notification is sent on the server (java firebase admin sdk) to that token I just received, there is this error:

```
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException
Requested entity was not found.
```

Also, if the user logs out of the app, I call messaging.deleteToken(currentToken) and unregister from server. But the javascript delete token method does not work and I get the error (dev tools browser console):

```
DELETE firebase-messaging.js:1 DELETE https://fcmregistrations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/registrations/[MY_TOKEN] 404
firebase-messaging.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occured while unsubscribing the user from FCM: FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occured while unsubscribing the user from FCM: Requested entity was not found. (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed). (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed).
at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-messaging.js:1:24434
```

So I cannot even delete that token that is actually given by the Firebase SDK.
Eventually, if I just unregister my service worker and refresh the page, I get another token and everything works again.

What am I missing? (I have the latest javascript firebase sdk 7.17.1; I found nothing else regarding this issue on google)

---

Portions of code are as follows (some are written in GWT, but only the wrapping part; the integration with firebase is in pure javascript):

**Frontpage** (window client):

```
//initialization in web client is done by calling this method
public final void initialize(String publicKey, FirebaseCallback callback) {
    usePublicVapidKey(publicKey);
    String context = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL(); //current web context (host + server web context)
    init_native(context , "fcm-sw-import.js", callback); // my service worker
}
```

init_native function contains:

```
var messaging = this
//$wnd is actually "window"  
$wnd.navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
     for (i = 0; i < registrations.length; i++) {
        if (registrations[i].active && registrations[i].active.scriptURL.includes('fcm-sw-import.js') == false) {
            registrations[i].unregister();
            console.log ("FCM SW unregistered other service workers: " + registrations[i], registrations[i]);
        }
            
        
    } 
    });

$wnd.navigator.serviceWorker.register(fcmServiceWorkerJSfile, {scope: '.'})
        .then(function(registration) {
            
            registration.update();
            messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
            $wnd.navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) {
                console.log('FCM SW ready');
        
            //request permissions, get token, register to server, register my callbacks etc.
            messaging.@...fcm.FirebaseMessaging::requestPermissionAndRetrieveToken (L...fcm/FirebaseCallback;)(callback);
            });
            
            //console.log("SW - registered");

     });
```

request permissions and get token:

```
    var messaging = this;
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
          messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
              messaging.currentFcmToken = currentToken;
              if (currentToken) {
                
                $wnd.navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function handler(event) {

                    ....
                        
                });
                
                ...
              } 
              else {
                // Show permission request.
                ...
                // Show permission UI.
               ...
              }
            })['catch'](function(err) { //use [catch] so gwt wont think is a keyword
                console.log(err);
            
                ... on error callback

            });
          
        // Callback fired if Instance ID token is updated.
          messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
            messaging.getToken().then(function(refreshedToken) {
              var oldToken = messaging.currentFcmToken;
              messaging.currentFcmToken = refreshedToken;
              ...on token refresh callback
            })['catch'](function(err) {
                
            });
          });
        
          messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
                ...
            });

        })['catch'](function(err) {
            
            ...
        });
```

---

**Service worker** is fcm-sw-import.js:

```
importScripts('app/fcm-sw-reg.js?v26'); //Production    
setupAndInit({
            apiKey: ...,
            authDomain: ...,
            databaseURL: ...,
            messagingSenderId: ...,
            projectId: ...,
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: ...,
            appId: ...
        }, '.', "e-cache-v1");
```

setupAndInit method is in "fcm-sw-reg.js":

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-messaging.js');
... other imports, vars


function setupAndInit(config, urlContext, cacheName) {
    //initialize(config, urlContext);
    
    SENDER_ID = config.messagingSenderId;
    urlContextPath = urlContext;
    

    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }
    
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    CACHE_NAME = cacheName;
    
    
    self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
        // Perform install steps
        event.waitUntil(
            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                logToConsole('SW - Opened cache');
                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
                  })
                  
              );
        self.skipWaiting(); // Activate worker immediately
    });
    
    

    self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
        self.clients.claim();
    });
    

    self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
          e.respondWith(
            caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
                return response || fetch(e.request);
            })
          );
        });


    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
          var wnd = self;
          
          logToConsole('SW - FCM Received fcm background message ', payload);
          if (payload.from != SENDER_ID) { //cancel if the sender does not match
              return;
          }
          
          var data = payload.data;
          var notifExporter = new evc.NotificationDetailsExporter(data);
          var notifDetails = notifExporter.getNotificationDetails();
          
          var notificationTitle;
          var notificationOptions;
          
          if (notifDetails != null) {
              var notificationTitle = notifDetails.title;
              var iconPath = data.frImLink ? data.frImLink : '';
              var text = data.string13 ? data.string13 : "";
              var value = data.value ? " - " + data.value : "";
              notificationOptions = {
                body: notifDetails.message,
                icon: iconPath,
                data: data
              };
          }
          
          
          
          logToConsole('SW - sending message to wclients...');
          clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
              clients.forEach(client => {
                  send_message_to_client(client, {ebasFCM:"true", data: payload.data});
              })
              
          })
          
          
          if (notificationTitle)
              return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
                      notificationOptions);
          else
              return null;
            
        });
        
    logToConsole("SW FCM - Initialized FCM worker: " + SENDER_ID + " at: " + urlContextPath);

    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {

      event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
        includeUncontrolled: true,
        type: "window"
      }).then(function(clientList) {
        logToConsole("SW FCM - Searching client list: ", clientList);
        for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
          var client = clientList[i];
          logToConsole("SW FCM - Searching client urls: ", client.url);
        }
        
        logToConsole("SW FCM - url context path: ", urlContextPath);
        logToConsole("SW FCM - notif click event: ", event);
        var notifExporter = new evc.NotificationDetailsExporter(event.notification.data);
        var toUrl = notifExporter.getNotificationContextUrl();
          
        if (clientList.length) {
            if (toUrl)
                send_message_to_client(clientList[0], {type: "openUrl", url: toUrl});
            
            return clientList[0].focus();
          }
        else if (clients.openWindow) {
            if (toUrl == null)
                toUrl = "";
            
            return clients.openWindow( urlContextPath + toUrl);
        }
          
      }));
      event.notification.close();
      
    });
    
    logToConsole('SW FCM - Setup fcm done');
}
```

---

Please advise. Thank you.